# Error: Undefined operation "#700e70 + 15%"

Tags: css, sass

Hey i'm learning Sass and been facing an issue when I try using a function. The code is returning ***Error: Undefined operation "#700e70 + 15%".***

Here's the code:

```
&:hover{
        background-color: lighten(a.$bg-color, 15%);
    }
```

The function:

```
@function lighten($color, $amount){
    $color: $color + $amount;
    @return $color;
}
```

The output:

```
Error: Undefined operation "#700e70 + 15%".
  ╷
2 │     $color: $color + $amount;
  │             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  style\util\_functions.scss 2:13       lighten()
  style\components\_buttons.scss 12:27  @forward
  style\components\index.scss 2:1       @use
  style\main.scss 1:1                   root stylesheet
```

Comment: SASS has already [built-in functions](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#lighten) `lighten()` and `darken()`.

Comment: Oh thank you, i just deleted the function i made and it is working now :D